# Help with Reading Logic Statement: $\forall x\in\mathbb Z, \exists y\in\mathbb Z, y=3x$

Tags: logic

$\forall x\in\mathbb Z, \exists y\in\mathbb Z, y=3x$

I just have a brain fart of a question, how would this be translated into words?
Would it go as such: For all $x$ in the set of integers, there exists a $y$ in the set of integers, such that $y=3x$.

And then following that, would the truth value of this statement be true?

Thank you!

Comment: It is true. Just let $y=3x$

Comment: Thank you, my brain is very much fried at the moment, I appreciate it.

Comment: The statement basically says, "Multiplying an integer by 3 produces another integer." On the other hand, if the statement was $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} \exists y \in\mathbb{Z}~(3y=x)$, this would be saying that every integer is divisible by 3, which is false.

Comment: Your translation is correct. More idiomatically and informally, for each integer $x$ there is an integer $y$ that is three times $x$. And yes, this is certainly true.

Comment: You're interpretation is correct.  It's an obvious statement and is meant to be obvious. But as obvious as it is, it's not necessarily a gimme. Have to know that multiplication of integers is closed, and that if you multiple an integer by three you get an integer. (Which hopefully we *do* all know that).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your translation is correct.

It is worth noting that $\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}(Px)$ is shorthand for $\forall x(x\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow Px)$. Its negation is $\exists x(x\in\mathbb{Z}\land\lnot Px)$, which shorthands to $\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}(\lnot Px)$.

So the statement, in full without any shorthand, would read: For any $x$, there is a $y$ such that, if $x$ is an integer, then $y$ is an integer and $y=3x$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your translation is correct, and the formula is true.

We can determine if the statement is true by seeing if we can find an integer y for any given x that satisfies y=3x

if x = 1, y = 3

if x = 0, y = 0

if x = -123, y = 369

I can see that for any integer value of x we can generate, the value of 3x will be an integer as well.  So this statement is true.

Now, if the formula was ∀∈ℤ,∃∈ℤ,x=3y the statement would not be true.

This is because for any integer x, there is not always going to be an integer y such that x=3y holds true.

We test this by generating any integer x value and seeing if we can find a corresponding integer y when plugged into the equation x = 3y.

Example:

if x = 6, then y = 2 (this works)
if x = 4, then there would not exist an integer y that satisfies the formula. (doesn't work)

And we see that if x is a number not divisible by 3, then there is not an integer that satisfies x = 3y

So this statement would be false